# How to send push notification from google assistant through Dialogflow fulfilment in Python

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing chatbot in google Dialogflow for google assistance, I've followed this [Documentation for showing Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#dialogflow). I've asked for the permission but now I'm stuck at the last step(`Exchange the key for an access token and send a notification`) in that documentation.

Can anybody please help me to do it. Which JSON response should I send from my Python fulfillment code?

Comment: Are you stuck on the "Exchange the key for an access token and send a notification" step?

Comment: Yes, I'm stuck at `Exchange the key for an access token and send a notification` step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, solved the problem. The code posted by @matthewayne has some mistakes, for example the request must be of the "POST" method and need to change some parameters in payload and header, hence it worked!, here I've changed some code and tried to request and it hit a notification!

I referred [this documentation to make it worked!](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#custompushmessage)

```
import io
import json

import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests

PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'path/to/json/service/account'

REQUIRED_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'

# Get access token
with io.open(PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_fi:
    credentials_info = json.load(json_fi)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    credentials_info, scopes=[REQUIRED_SCOPE])
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.token
}

payload = {
    'customPushMessage': {
        'userNotification': {
            'title': 'Notification title',
            'text': 'Simple Text'
        },
        'target': {
            'userId': '<USER_ID>',
            'intent': '<INTENT>',
            # Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
            'locale': 'en-US'
        }
    }
}

r = requests.request("POST", 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(str(r.status_code) + ': ' + r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import io
import json

import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests

PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'path/to/json/service/account'

REQUIRED_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'

# Get access token
with io.open(PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_fi:
    credentials_info = json.load(json_fi)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            credentials_info,  scopes=[REQUIRED_SCOPE])
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + credentials.token
}

payload = {'customPushMessage': {
    'userNotification': {
      'title': '<NOTIFICATION_TITLE>',
    },
    'target': {
      'userId': '<USER_ID>',
      'intent': '<INTENT>',
      # Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
      'locale': '<LOCALE>'
    },
  }
}

r = requests.get('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', json=payload, headers=headers)

print(str(r.status_code) + ': ' + r.text)
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but it gives `Error: 400` `Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.`  P.S. I've updated my bot from v1 to v2

Comment: My payload target json is formed like `'target': {
      'userId': 'ABwppHEtlrhbdLhrSplziZ3mT8pFMkhbo4j6XFYT89GFrqwtV93B2EJr7BDOonpre0eoYhzmuM1bWMygbJIAmhUBZxc-',
      'intent': 'tell_latest_tip',
      'locale': 'en-US'
    }`

If any changes required or I've made any mistake then please let me know. I'm not sure about `locale` and `intent` name. are they correct?

Comment: Hey, Thank you your code doesn't work but it gave me a way to find the solution and with some alteration in your code the push notification functionality works! Thanks, man!