# Daily Update from DialogFlow fulfillment python in google assistant

Tags: python, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing an application with Dialogflow and Actions on Google which requires to send daily birthday notification in Google Assistant.

I'm following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily) to send daily updates. But I'm having trouble because of the language barrier.

I'm developing backed in Python and using fulfillment to serve the request, but that documentation is in Node.js. So I need help to send daily updates.

I've done up to `Console setup`. Please guide me for further process.(Which JSON req. should I sent?)

Comment: Seems like this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821919/how-to-send-push-notification-from-google-assistant-through-dialogflow-fulfilmen

Comment: It is a different question, not a duplicate @techpeace, it is for push notification and this question is about the daily update, it's different functionality - you can schedule updates at a specific time and all, it requires a different configuration to do that!

Answer (score 1):

If you look down that documentation page a bit [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily#configure_the_subscription) and click the **JSON** tab, you'll see the specific format you need to configure the subscription to your birthday updates.

Since you're not using a client library, you'll need to write the Python code yourself to respond with the appropriate JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any client library for python? and if it is there then how to use it?

Comment: @JayPatel There's [an official client library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2), but it isn't necessary to build webhook fulfillment endpoints. Check out [this example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-weather-python), as well as this [unofficial library](https://github.com/DeveloperBibin/python-aog).