# Send push notification through Dialogflow in python for google actions app

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I was trying to buid an app to send push notification throguh dialogflow fullfuillment to user. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#dialogflow) link, now I've got the update permission (see screenshot 1 and 2 at the bottom of the quetion). I followed the stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821919/how-to-send-push-notification-from-google-assistant-through-dialogflow-fulfilmen) to write this piece of python code to send a notification, I'm able to run it, and got a status code of 200, but I never receive my test notification on my GoogleHomeApp/Google speaker. Can you help?

```py
import io
import json

import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests

PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'account.json'

REQUIRED_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'

# Get access token
with io.open(PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_fi:
    credentials_info = json.load(json_fi)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    credentials_info, scopes=[REQUIRED_SCOPE])
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.token
}

text = 'Hello, this is a test notification'
user_id = "ABwppHFyNFT1fqDRmEug_k2ZKu43hM7xbLmgShN_ESww0iwPLQh-BU6n4T-e3rUOiVqRBWNn5q6bOg"

payload = {
    'customPushMessage': {
        'userNotification': {
            'title': 'Recent News',
            'text': text,
        },
        'target': {
            'userId': user_id,
            'intent': 'Recent News',
            # Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
            'locale': 'en-US'
        }
    }
}

r = requests.request("POST", 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(f"A push notification has been sent to user {user_id} with status code {r.status_code}.")
```

This is the screenshot of simulator:
[image: screenshot of simulator]

This is the logs I got on my localhost, shows that I got the permission to send push notification to the user.
[image: screenshot of fullfuilment]

I went to the stackdriver logging to check the logs, this is what i got:

[image: stackdriver logging]

Comment: Notifications won't show up on a Google Home, but they should appear on a phone. Can you verify the user ID is correct and hasn't changed?

Comment: hi @NickFelker , I can confirm the id is correct (copy-paste), the strange thing is that the id changes everytime I try to request update permission.

Comment: It seems like your user [may be a guest](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data#determining_and_handling_user_verification_status) and doesn't have a stable identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [Official Push Notifications Documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#dialogflow) you'll find the note which indicates that as of now, **push notifications are not supported** on the [voice-activated speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_speaker).

[image]

Soon they might release the update but we never know! You might ask the support team regarding the updates.