# The caller does not have permission. Actions API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, push-notification, action

I'm trying to build a bot on Actions Builder that send to itself a push notification. I configure the intents properly and get push token and implement the code given by documentation (https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#exchange_the_key_for_an_access_token_and_send_a_notification).

This is my code:

```
action.handle('SendPushIntent', async (conv) => {
  const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
  console.log(serviceAccount.client_email); // I verified that service account is the same here as my GCP account.
  let client = auth.fromJSON(serviceAccount);
  client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'];
  let notification = {
    userNotification: {
      title: 'Example',
      text: 'Body'
    },
    target: {
      userId: conv.user.params.pushToken, // The push token stored, I verified is not empty, null or undefined
      intent: 'PushReceptorIntent',
      locale: conv.user.locale,
    },
  };
  client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(`Auth error: ${err}`); // No error here
    }
    request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
      'auth': {
        'bearer': tokens.access_token,
      },
      'json': true,
      'body': {'customPushMessage': notification, 'isInSandbox': true},
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`API request error: ${err}`);
      }
      console.log(`${httpResponse.statusCode}: ` + `${httpResponse.statusMessage}`);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
    });
  });
});
```

When I try to send a push I have this error
`{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}`

I already got a service account key with owner permissions and give it to my code, as documentation requires https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications#get_a_service_account_key

This is the chart of Actions API, only got 403 as response. I don't have idea what is going wrong.
[image]

I already did the following steps:

- Disable/enable Actions API
- Generate service account
- Verified that services account has owner permission

Hope you can help me with this!

**Edit Oct, 8th**

Added Cloud Asset Owner permission to my service account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message **“{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}”** is returned if you do not have permission to export assets or get the history on an organization, project, or folder.

To address this issue, request access from your project, folder, or organization admin. Depending on the assets you are trying to export or get history for, you will need one of the following roles or other roles that include the required Cloud Asset API permissions:

- cloudasset.viewer
- cloudasset.owner

Please review [this document](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/faq#no-cai-permissione) to see information about how to obtain more detail information about this issue.

If you want to know more about the access control options available to you for the Cloud Asset API, [please follow this link.](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/access-control#required_permissions)

If you want to know more about roles and permissions, [please follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already add Cloud Asset Owner permission to the service account I using, but still not working and get the same response message. I updated  the post with the screenshot of my project permission principal list showing the permission you referred.

Comment: Perhaps you can try the answer in this thread, the user had a similar issue to you. There is an example code, that might be useful in your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821919/how-to-send-push-notification-from-google-assistant-through-dialogflow-fulfilmen

Comment: At the end that was an Actions API error. I reached support from them and now everything works as expected! Thank you for your assistance!